# Tracing: Chrome Debugging Protocol

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, javascript-debugger

**Task** I want to collect js function call events in chrome extension using [debugger API](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/).

**Problem** When I collect all events by listening to `Tracing.dataCollected` its very huge array of events which I don't want to collect. Each of collected event is object of the form `{cat, dur,name,ph,pid,tid,ts}` However in official API documentation there is no details about event categories therefore can't limit collection.

**Required** Where I can find detailed about these event categories?

Comment: I don't know but the page you linked says you can filter the collected categories in the  `start` method, and there's `getCategories` method which you can use to obtain the full list and then simply guess which items to filter out.

Comment: see [Tracing.getCategories](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Tracing/#method-getCategories) and [Tracing.TraceConfig](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Tracing/#type-TraceConfig)